# Application level auth token for Facebook?

Tags: facebook, token, authentication, access-token

So I have an app that needs to access public info, but needs an auth token. Specifically, I want to get the comments from public pages, and that requires an access token. Ideally, I'd like some sort of "global" auth token, since I'm not trying to access anything that isn't public anyway. Is there any way to have an app-level auth token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can authenticate as an application instead of using the user.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/